# openlayers3 prevent screen updates

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm working on a openlayers3 application and we will need to reorder the display layers.  I would like to be able to prevent display updates until we are finished changing the layer collection.  Is that possible?
thanks, D

Comment: how are you reordering the display of layers ? z-Index maybe ?

Answer (score -2):

*may be helpful:*

```
var features = getYourFeature
```

or

```
var features = layer.getSource().getFeatures();
```

then do something with the features with your own business
it's a collection(array) of feature 
then reset the features to the layer like this

```
layer.getSource().clear();
layer.getSource().addFeatures(features);
```

*/